# Adobe analytics- Exit Click coming always with page view for all links within app

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

Recently implemented adobe analytics in our application and i can see  all adobe clicks well. But somehow for all link clicks within application am seeing Exit click(which is not needed) along with page views.

Can anyone know why exit click is getting triggered along with page view. its not supposed to trigger unless we navigate from our current application.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Launch and Adobe Analytics Extension, navigate to the extension configuration, and under **LINK TRACKING**, for every domain you do *not* want to track as exit links, add an entry for the domain under the **Never Track** field. Domains can be partially matched, e.g. putting ".mysite.com" will count for [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), foo.mysite.com, etc.

If you do not want any exit link tracking to fire at all, then you can skip the above and just uncheck the **Track outbound links** checkbox.

If you are not using Launch / Adobe Analytics Extension (e.g. full custom coding somewhere), then within your code, look for these variables:

[`s.trackExternalLinks`](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/implementation/vars/config-vars/trackexternallinks.html?lang=en) - This controls whether or not to track exit links (*same as the **Track outbound links** checkbox in the Launch extension*). Since you see exit link triggering, this should currently be set to `true`. Change it to `false` or remove it if you do not want to track any links as exit link clicks.

[`s.linkInternalFilters`](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/implementation/vars/config-vars/linkinternalfilters.html?lang=en) - This is a comma delimited list of domains to match against the link's `href` attribute (*similar to the **Never Track** field in the Launch extensio*n). Anything on this list will count as internal and exit link tracking will *not* trigger. If you *do* want exit link tracking in general, but want to suppress it for links that point to other pages of your site, leave `s.trackExternalLinks=true`, and add domain(s) here.